# Editing Wordpress plugin but it isn't getting updated

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

I made a small change to a **wordpress** plugin's css file.

Original line was:

```
.music-store-header{position:relative;clear:both;/*min-width:645px*/;margin-bottom:10px;white-space: normal !important; display: block !important;}
```

I added the left margin, as follows:

```
.music-store-header{margin-left: 15pc; position:relative;clear:both;/*min-width:645px*/;margin-bottom:10px;white-space: normal !important; display: block !important;}
```

This change, however is not happening.

Comment: may be some caching plugin affect.

Comment: How to remove it?

Comment: disable caching plugin and check in incognito browser.

Answer (score 0):

try Ctrl + F5 ! if not happened go to your theme css and add :

```
.music-store-header{margin-left: 15pc;}
```

to your code . if not happened again . add  !important before ;